# Set y limits in Bar Chart ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a bar chart which shows the sales of products in a particular category. [This is the bar chart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLhY2.png) As you can see it is not very clear so I am trying to set limits for the Y axis.

I create the bar chart with the following line:

```
bakerySales <- ggplot(sales_bakery, aes(ProductName, ProductSales))+ 
stat_summary(fun.y=sum,geom="bar",colour="red",fill="red",show.legend = 
FALSE)
```

I then go on to apply a theme to the bar chart using:

```
bakerySales <- bakerySales +
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 14, angle = 60, 
    hjust = 1),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 14),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 1),
    legend.position = "none",
    plot.title = element_text(lineheight = 8, face = "bold"))
```

I have tried to set the limits for the y axis using:

```
bakerySales <- bakerySales + ylim(5000,10000)
```

When I do this I lose the content of the bar chart, [It looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M65nS.png)

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to zoom in on specifix ylimits, you could use the coord_cartesian function. I do not have the bakerysales dataset, this is an example using mtcars data:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = gear, y = qsec)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=sum,geom="bar",colour="red",fill="red",show.legend = FALSE) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(200, 300))
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I was setting my limits outside where I was creating my bar chart, when I tried your answer it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want

```
+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(5000,10000))


df <- data.frame(x = c("a","b"), y = c(1000, 2000))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(500,3000))
```